# WebStorm Dart Project - Generate sample content bring just two sample

Tags: dart, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2016.3.2 (last version now).

When I try to create a New Dart Project, on *Generate sample content* it bring just two samples:

- Dart Wep App
- Dart Command Line App

On old WebStorm version, there was more options, like Angular, Polymer, etc.

Is there a way to do WebStorm to get more options, specially Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm used the `stagehand` package to create projects from templates.

If you check the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehand you'll see that `Polymer` was removed in `1.0.19`

The below a sceenshot from my WebStorm show 2 Angular templates though

[image]

To get your install `stagehand` updated to the newest version execute

```
pub global activate stagehand
```

I'm not sure if this is the reason why you don't get Angular templates listed.

Comment: Thanks,  but it is occur the following problem: `C:\dart-sdk\bin>pub global activate stagehand
Package stagehand is currently active at version 1.0.14.
Resolving dependencies...
...
Precompiling executables...
Loading source assets...
Failed to precompile stagehand:stagehand:
Unhandled exception:
Could not import "package:http/http.dart" from "package:stagehand/src/cli_app.da
rt": Failure getting http://localhost:55713/packages/http/http.dart:
  404 Not Found
null`

Comment: What problem? . .

Comment: `Failed to precompile stagehand:stagehand: Unhandled exception: Could not import "package:http/http.dart" from "package:stagehand/src/cli_app.da rt": Failure getting http://localhost:55713/packages/http/http.dart: 404 Not Found null`

Comment: Sounds weird. You could try `pub cache repair` and then try again

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work.